# WIX. Set environment variable and run application after installation

Tags: wix, environment-variables

I developed a custom installer with WIX for a .NET application. 
In this installer I set environment variable

```
<Environment Id="COMPLUS_Version" Action="set" Part="all" Name="COMPLUS_Version" 
                 Permanent="yes" System="yes" Value="v4.0.30319" />
```

and after installation I run application (this environment variable need to be set for correct running apllication).

```
<UI Id="MyWixUI_Mondo">
  <UIRef Id="WixUI_Advanced" />
  <Publish Dialog="ExitDialog"
      Control="Finish"
      Event="DoAction"
      Value="LaunchApplication">WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALCHECKBOX = 1 and NOT Installed</Publish>
</UI>
<Property Id="WixShellExecTarget" Value="[#Application]" /> 

<CustomAction Id="LaunchApplication"
    BinaryKey="WixCA"
    DllEntry="WixShellExec"
    Impersonate="yes" />
```

But, sometimes it doesn't work. For example, in Windows 7 Enterprise x86 apllication run after installation with errors (only after installation).

UPD. This problem appear when UAC is disabled.

Comment: What kind of errors? Why do you connect the errors to the environment variable? And BTW, it is the installation ended with errors, or the application starts with errors?

Comment: This kind of error appear when this environment variable not set. For example, if I set variable manually before installation, application start without errors. Installation end successfully, but application starts with errors.

Comment: according to what you say your installer doesn't create the environment variable. did you place it inside a component? try to create a simple environment variable